# How to make a footer stick to the bottom of the page

Tags: html, css, footer

I have read all the tutorials on how to make the footer at the bottom of the webpage but still i'm unable to do it for my site.

The links i have referred are

- [How do you get the footer to stay at the bottom of a Web page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42294/how-do-you-get-the-footer-to-stay-at-the-bottom-of-a-web-page)
- [Making my footer stick to bottom of the page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20774383/making-my-footer-stick-to-bottom-of-the-page)
- [Ways to stick footer to the bottom a page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2354361/ways-to-stick-footer-to-the-bottom-a-page)
- [making the footer stick the bottom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17024873/making-the-footer-stick-the-bottom)

None of it worked..!

**CSS**

```
#footer1 {
clear: both;
background-color: #333;
width: 1200px;
min-width: 100%;
width: 100%;
bottom: 0;
position: relative;
height: 50px;
border-top:5px solid #1b9bff;
}
```

Here is the dummy fiddle of my site

## [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JrbMm/)

This is the fiddle i have tried but there is a bug in it too

1. http://jsfiddle.net/andresilich/fVpp2/1/

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you get the footer to stay at the bottom of a Web page?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42294/how-do-you-get-the-footer-to-stay-at-the-bottom-of-a-web-page)

Comment: search: 'sticky footer' in google.

Comment: @Danield it didn't work..!! I have searched for it

Comment: @KarlViiburg I have used the method which you have suggested in the link but still i'm unable to bring it to the bottom

Comment: @AmarnathBalasubramanian - you should include in your question exactly what your requirements are and what you have tried and show how the things you tried don't work. Then it's more likely someone will be able to help you.

Comment: Try to simplify your website in a fiddle using the solutions mentioned in the above questions.

Comment: @Danield I have added a set of fiddles, check that out

Comment: have you tried this: http://ryanfait.com/resources/footer-stick-to-bottom-of-page/

Comment: Now your question is a lot better :)

Comment: you want stickyfooter like facebook message system?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<div id="container">
  <div id="content"></div>
</div>
<div id="footer">My Sticky Footer</div>
```

CSS:

```
html, body, #container { height: 100%; }
body > #container { height: auto; min-height: 100%; }

#footer {
   clear: both;
   position: relative;
   z-index: 10;
   height: 3em;
   margin-top: -3em;
}

#content { padding-bottom: 3em; }
```

Comment: if you want to use this you should also add a padding equals the height of your footer to the body

Comment: I don't want the footer to be fixed i want it to be at the bottom of webpage..!!

Comment: Hey this didn't work in my case..! :( Thanks for your time..!

Answer (score 0):

Add/Edit as following

```
#body {
margin-bottom: 85px;
position: relative;
}

#footer1 {
position: fixed;
}
```

I guess this is what you want

```
* html #form1 {
    height:100%; 
}

#form1 {
    min-height: 100%;
    position: relative;
}

#body {
    padding-bottom: 50px; /* padding-bottom should be equal to the footer height (this keeps the footer from overlapping the content) */
}

#footer1 {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    clear: both;
    bottom: 0;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
```

Comment: i don't want the footer to be fixed i want it at the bottom of the page

Comment: I am not getting you, footer at bottom of page? do you mean footer should be at bottom of page every time regardless of scroll position?

Answer (score 0):

Following the code of [this method](http://ryanfait.com/resources/footer-stick-to-bottom-of-page/) - you need to to:

1) Place your footer outside the form

2) Add height: 100% on form

3) Set negative bottom margin to form according to the height of the footer.

```
form {
    min-height: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto -150px; /*footer 150px high */
}
```

**[Modified Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JrbMm/8/)**